# If every nonempty subset $S$ of $X$ has a largest element, what do we call $X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition, well-orders

A totally ordered set $X$ is said to be *well ordered* if every nonempty subset $S$ of $X$ has a smallest element.

Here I am asking about an analogous definition: If every nonempty subset $S$ of $X$ has a largest element, what do we call $X$?

I have heard a lot about well-orderness of sets and am wondering if the "symmetrical" property that every nonempty subset has a largest element is equally important and deserves a familiar name.

Comment: I'd change the *direction* of the order relation and call it well-ordered. Or maybe "well-ordered from above" or STLT

Comment: I don't think there is a standard term, but it is essentially "well ordered under the reverse order" or "well ordered under $\geq$ ".

Comment: "Reverse well ordered" has some Google hits.  You could also say that your order satisfies the *ascending chain condition*.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, this is most commonly called "co-well-ordered".  Other terms you might encounter are "reverse well-ordered", "anti-well-ordered", or "converse well-ordered".